# gparted insists disk is mounted but umount command says not mounted

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

The disk is a former 18.04 boot disk I've repurposed as an external USB drive. After looking around I see this happens with LVM but on installation to that disk I did not intentionally request LVM but perhaps this has become a much preferred default?

Gparted shows the disk with two ext4 partitions. The lower partition shows as locked but I don't see any indication of why it is locked. fuser for the mount returns empty.

I want to repartition into one partition and format into ext4.

What can I use to further question the state of the drive and how can I get to the format I'm looking for?

Thank to commenters. When I ran the mount command, I saw that the drive was mounted to /media/stephen rather than to the directory I had set in the fstab. I know how this happened but I will spare you. There is no insight to be gained other than the advice to never ever forget what you've done, advice that is both excellent and absolutely useless.

So after correcting that, gparted went about its business as expected. 
All is well.

Comment: Cant tell from what little you posted. What file system, LVM? What is the output of fdisk and mount ?

Comment: Since it's an external USB drive, perhaps the block device is mounted by udisks rather than mount? what does `udisksctl status` say?

Comment: Please run the following commands, `sudo lsblk -f` and  `sudo lsblk -m` and `sudo parted -ls` and `df -h` and edit your original question to show the output of those commands. Indent each line (of the output) in order to render it as 'code'. This will help us help you.